# Webpages for specialized communities

Tags: ho.history-overview, career, soft-question, sociology-of-math

First, my apology for this soft question. My excuse was that I really think this may be of interest to the community. I would understand if it gets closed (I have advocated closing some soft questions myself, so it's fair).

**Background/Motivation**: Recently at an AMS meeting I decided to attend a special session outside my interests and had a lot of fun. Also, to learn about what is going on in a different but related area, I found it  very useful to look at some recent conferences and start by  skimming the list of speakers and abstracts/notes. So a website with recent and upcoming conferences would be useful. They are not always easy to find with Google.

**Requirements**: Since this is soft, let's take some care to make sure it will not be too easy to answer. So let's define "specialized community" to be "there is at least one AMS special session devoted to (part of) it. Also, the more useful the website is the better (for example, one should preferably contains list of conferences, and perhaps more)

**Examples**: here is one I visit frequently: [for commutative algebra](http://www.commalg.org/)

Another one I found recently and like a lot: [Finite dimensional algebras](http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~fdlist/)

> Surely there must be others?

Comment: Close it?  No way -- this has got to be one of the most useful soft questions we have yet had on this site.

Comment: May I suggest that this is one of those questions where there should be just **one** answer which everyone adds their sites to (those without enough rep can leave comments/answers to be added and then deleted).  That way, the list can be organised more usefully than by "votes" or dates.

Comment: @Andrew: that is a good idea, but unfortunately now it is a bit late to do that. Perhaps after a while I can make an answer compiling all the links? 

Comment: I dunno; isn't it pretty easy to just skim down the page and click the links that interest you?  Am I missing something, Andrew?

Answer (score 12):

[Open source mathematics software](http://sagemath.org/) -- we've had a lot of talks about Sage in special sessions, and next year in Boston we'll have an AMS minicourse on Sage.

Answer (score 8):

There is also the [Number Theory Web](http://www.numbertheory.org/ntw/).

Answer (score 6):

Kiran Kedlaya maintains a list of upcoming conferences in arithmetic geometry: http://scripts.mit.edu/~kedlaya/wiki/index.php?title=Conferences_in_Arithmetic_Geometry

Ravi Vakil has a list of upcoming conferences in algebraic geometry:
http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/conferences.html

Answer (score 5):

Dispersive wiki: http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/DispersiveWiki/index.php/Main_Page

Complexity zoo (if computer science counts): http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo

Deep Inference (from structural proof theory): http://alessio.guglielmi.name/res/cos/

n-lab (category theory): http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage

Comment: Arg, how could I forget the nLab??

Answer (score 4):

Here comes some sites that list upcoming (and also previous) conferences in 
the field of operator algebras

One maintained by Paulo Pinto: http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~ppinto/conf2004.html

Another maintained by Michael Anshelevich: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~manshel/meet.html

And a third maintained by Narutaka Ozawa: http://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~narutaka/schedule.html

Operator algebra page of N. C. Phillips: http://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~ncp/OpAlgResources/OpAlgPages/opalg.html

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if these have special sessions, but they are pretty broad:

- [K-theory](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/)
- [category theory](http://www.mta.ca/~cat-dist/)

Comment: @David: excellent, thanks! Broad is OK, by my definition.

Answer (score 3):

Jon McCammond's [geometric group theory page](http://math.ucsb.edu/~jon.mccammond/geogrouptheory/).

Answer (score 2):

[Compressed Sensing](http://dsp.rice.edu/cs)

Answer (score 2):

[Galois Theory Web Page](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~galois/)

[Valuation Theory Home Page](http://math.usask.ca/fvk/Valth.html)

Comment: Dear Pete, thanks! I especially like the Galois Theory page, but it looks like the site has not been updated for a while. Do you know if there is a newer site, surely the community still exist? 

Comment: @Hailong: unfortunately I do not know of a newer / more active site.  

Answer (score 2):

Foundations of mathematics: http://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/

Answer (score 2):

As far as logic goes, there is the [Association of Symbolic Logic website](http://www.aslonline.org/).  It has a very comprehensive [list of logic meetings](http://www.aslonline.org/other_meetings.php), which includes the [ASL meetings](http://www.aslonline.org/asl_meetings.php), the [officially sponsored meetings](http://www.aslonline.org/sponsored_meetings.php), and more.

Answer (score 2):

Sarah Whitehouse keeps a list of meetings in [algebraic topology](http://www.sarah-whitehouse.staff.shef.ac.uk/btconfs.html) and related areas.

Answer (score 2):

A few more for Logic:

[Mathematical Logic Around the World](http://world.logic.at/) contains a lot of useful information about Logic departments, Logic journals, LaTeX for Logicians etc. The events section is a little outdated though.

The [European Set Theory Society](http://ests.wordpress.com/) has conference announcements as well as slides from the conferences.

There is also the [Young Set Theory Network](http://young-set-theory.net/wiki/Main_Page), which has conference announcements, and hopefully will have more things in the future.

Answer (score 1):

[Motivic or $A^1$-homotopy theory](http://a1homotopy.tiddlyspot.com/).

[Affine algebraic geometry](http://sci-tech.ksc.kwansei.ac.jp/~kayo/AAG_e.html).

[Cluster Algebra Portal](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~fomin/cluster.html).

Comment: how many of those tiddlyspot websites are there for math? how hard are they to make?

Comment: Sean, the homotopy one is the only one I know. 