# Sites/technologies to help to keep updated with your area

Tags: soft-question

I am currently a PhD student, and as everyone else, I try to keep updated with articles in my area. I was wondering better ways to keep updated, particularly, 
what technologies could help to do this job quicker.

I have seen for example this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56807/how-to-be-updated-with-current-advances-in-mathematics), but I believe my question is more specific.

For example, I set RSS tags on arXiv to be sent to my email with some important key-topics in my area. I also follow questions about it in Mathoverflow, setting email alerts as well. And recently I set Google Scholar to send me emails when some authors on my field either publish new articles or when they are cited by someone else. I like to use [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/) as well, but to be honest, I did not manage to make much with it.

I would appreciate any suggestion for this workflow of getting updated and I apologize if this question is too subjective.

Comment: Great Question.  Wrong forum.  It sounds like you are in an academic setting, so try academia.stackexchange. (I can imagine a variant of this more appropriate for industry or the stackexchange forum for the workplace.) Gerhard "Every Query Has Its Place" Paseman, 2017.03.27.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted there: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87170/sites-technologies-to-help-to-keep-updated-with-your-area
Should I now delete or close the question in this forum?

Comment: My preference is to leave it for those few wise enough to search for questions before submitting.  However, the community usually handles the disposition of the post.  (And thanks for all the links.) Gerhard "Endeavours Not To Say 'Disposal'" Paseman, 2017.03.27.

Comment: Apparently people didn't find it very appropriate for the academia forum either, as there were only down votes there.

Comment: At this writing, at least two more people disapproved than approved at Academia. However, you also got a reasonable comment. Gerhard "I'd Say You Broke Even" Paseman, 2017.03.28.

Comment: This site helps to sort arXiv articles useful to you based on the ratings that you give to some papers: http://arxivist.com/

Comment: This site seems very useful, thank you very much!